# Logic error in checking number even program?

Tags: javascript

I was just reading Eloquent JS and have decided to do some of the exercises.

Basically, I'm trying to create a program that checks for even number without using `%`. Even number prints `true` and odd prints `false`.

```
function isEven(n) {
  if (n < 0)
    n = -n;
  if (n == 2)
    return true;
  if (n == 1)
    return false;
  if (n > 2)
    isEven(n - 2);
}
```

However:

```
console.log(isEven(50));
// → undefined
console.log(isEven(75));
// → undefined
console.log(isEven(-1));
// → false
```

I've tried slipping in `console.log` in the function and I can't find the problem :/

```js
function isEven(n) {
  document.write(n + "<br>");
  if (n < 0)
    n = -n;
  if (n == 2)
    return true;
  if (n == 1)
    return false;
  if (n > 2)
    isEven(n - 2);
}

document.write(isEven(50) + "<br>");
// → true
document.write(isEven(75) + "<br>");
// → false
document.write(isEven(-1) + "<br>");
// → ??
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to return the last `isEven(n - 2);`.

```
function isEven(n) {
  if (n < 0)
    n = -n;
  if (n == 2)
    return true;
  if (n == 1)
    return false;
  if (n > 2)
    return isEven(n - 2);
}
```

Comment: I'm very bad it the fundamentals. May I ask why is the `return` necessary?

Comment: @Daniel Cheung: Every function has a return value. You are using console.log(fn), which is essentially console.log of the return value of fn. So you have to ensure that your fn returns a valid value if you want to log it.

Comment: Never mind, I got it. It's like a line of `true`s returning back to the start.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the return

```
function isEven(n) {
  if (n < 0)
    n = -n;
  if (n == 2)
    return true;
  if (n == 1)
    return false;
  if (n > 2)
    return isEven(n - 2);    // <-----------
}
```